# BufferedReader not reading data but shows value in debug mode

Tags: android, sockets, libgdx, serversocket

I have implemented Socket for a multiplayer game using libGdx.

Client side

```
 private void startClient(String ip, int port) {
        SocketHints socketHints = new SocketHints();
        // Socket will time our in 4 seconds
        socketHints.connectTimeout = 4000;
        //create the socket and connect to the server entered in the text box ( x.x.x.x format ) on port 9021
        Socket socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, ip, port, 
socketHints);
        try {
            System.out.println("JoinScreen.startClient");
            // write our entered message to the stream
            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
            out.write("testtest shine \n".getBytes());
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Server code

```
  private void startThreadServer() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("HotspotHomeScreen.run");
                ServerSocketHints serverSocketHint = new ServerSocketHints();

                serverSocketHint.acceptTimeout = 0;


                ServerSocket serverSocket = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(Net.Protocol.TCP, mPort, serverSocketHint);
                String messageStr = null;

                while (true) {
                    // Create a socket
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(null);
                    System.out.println("while true");
                    int value = 0;
                    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    try {
                        while ((value = buffer.read()) != -1) {
                            char c = (char) value;
                            if (value != 0 && value != 155)
                                messageStr = messageStr + c;
                            // Read to the next newline (\n) and display that text on labelMessage
                            System.out.println("HotspotHomeScreen.run  " + buffer.readLine());
                            System.out.println("test messageStr = " + messageStr);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("testnjnihg test" + messageStr);
                    System.out.println("HostScreen last line");
                }
            }
        }).start(); // And, start the thread running
    }
```

The BufferedReader is invoked after starting the server on one device,but data cannot read. When I switch to debug mode, after reaching  `while ((value = buffer.read()) != -1) {` the buffer shows all the data I sent in the debugger console,but the execution stops there. Sorry for my bad Language

Comment: Are you sure those println()'s are not getting printed? I feel it is an infinite while-loop as the read will return -1 only on end-of-stream which is not possible as per the current code!

Comment: ya..its not printing...can you help me to right code, if you dont mind